# I'm trying to send a POST request to my server from my react application but however i keep getting a status 400 Bad Request error

Tags: reactjs

here is my code

```
export const createProduct = (userId,token,product) =>{
    return fetch(`${API}/product/create/${userId}`,{
        method:"POST",
            headers:{
                Accept : "application/json",
                Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body : product
    }).then(response =>{
        return  response.json();
        //console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: If you get 400 then the issue doesn't come from React, check your server and see why it returns you a 400 status code. You are probably not sending the right data to server or the required amount of params

Comment: You *may* need to use `body: JSON.stringify(product)` rather than `body: product`. Without knowing what is in `product`, and what is expected by your API, no further help can be given.